# Multiple Ad Units on one activty from different publihser Allowed in android?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I want to ask if can I put multiple ad units on a single `Activity`, each unit belonging to a different publisher. Like I put ad of publisher A on top and Ad banner of publisher B at bottom, is it allowed?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you check the terms of service of A and B publishers...?

Comment: For admob using multiple banner on same activity is not allowed.

Comment: I know that multiple units of Admob are not allowed on same activity. But i am concerned about 1 unit of admob ad other unit of ABC is allowed on same activity? OR i just want to know does admob allowed any other publisher unit on same activity. On Website we can put multiple units of different publishers so it should be allowed i think on android activity as well